# Coordinate-based interpolation of values in time series format

Tags: arcgis-pro, interpolation

I have three different streamflow gauge station points along a river. For each point, I have streamflow values as timeseries. Between these station points (Red triangles on the map) I have additional points (green dots on the map) that I need to estimate streamflow values for each timestamp. I have attached a sample dataset. In the `Station points` dataset, x and y are the projected coordinate systems (I can convert to GCS if necessary) and streamflow values are attached.
In `Additional points`, I created random points between station points along the river. And the streamflow values are empty.

What I need is to estimate `streamflow` values for each point based on values at station points.

I used several tools in ArcGIS Pro (Kriging, IDW) but I could not quite understand how to apply interpolation for timeseries based on coordinates. Both ArcGIS or Python solution would work.

[image]

```py
import pandas as pd

# Station points dataset
station_points_data = {
    'Time': ['time1', 'time2', 'time3', 'time4', 'time5'] * 3,
    'Streamflow': [0.262780336, 0.262780336, 0.262780336, 0.262780336, 0.262780336,
                   2.180397188, 2.180397188, 2.180397188, 2.180397188, 2.180397188,
                   2.828853015, 2.828853015, 2.828853015, 2.828853015, 2.828853015],
    'x': [449143.36, 449143.36, 449143.36, 449143.36, 449143.36,
          459126.15, 459126.15, 459126.15, 459126.15, 459126.15,
          459879.74, 459879.74, 459879.74, 459879.74, 459879.74],
    'y': [4486892.33, 4486892.33, 4486892.33, 4486892.33, 4486892.33,
          4492501.09, 4492501.09, 4492501.09, 4492501.09, 4492501.09,
          4494096.5, 4494096.5, 4494096.5, 4494096.5, 4494096.5]
}
station_points_df = pd.DataFrame(station_points_data)

# Additional points dataset
additional_points_data = {
    'Time': ['time1', 'time2', 'time3', 'time4', 'time5'] * 4,
    'Streamflow': [None] * 20,
    'x': [449160.7865, 449160.7865, 449160.7865, 449160.7865, 449160.7865,
          449205.7511, 449205.7511, 449205.7511, 449205.7511, 449205.7511,
          449328.8121, 449328.8121, 449328.8121, 449328.8121, 449328.8121,
          449449.0332, 449449.0332, 449449.0332, 449449.0332, 449449.0332],
    'y': [4486996.628, 4486996.628, 4486996.628, 4486996.628, 4486996.628,
          4487129.155, 4487129.155, 4487129.155, 4487129.155, 4487129.155,
          4487116.139, 4487116.139, 4487116.139, 4487116.139, 4487116.139,
          4487304.328, 4487304.328, 4487304.328, 4487304.328, 4487304.328]
}
additional_points_df = pd.DataFrame(additional_points_data)
```